# Vertically & horinzontally align multiple div children in container

Tags: html, css

I currently have the following code:

```
<div id="container">
     <div class="card">1</div>
     <div class="card">2</div>
     <div class="card">3</div>
     <div class="card">4</div>
</div>

<style>
    #container{
       width:100%;
       height:100%;
       overflow-y:auto;
       position:absolute;
       left:0; top:10px;
       padding:10px;
    }

    .card{
       width:100px; height:100px; margin:10px;
       float:left;
    }
</style>
```

I am trying to vertically and horizontally align the div boxes so that the more boxes that appear, it still stays both vertically and horizontally centred in the container. For example:

[image]
Example of what it would look like with 4 cards which fit in the container..

[image]
Example of what it would look like with 12 cards which overflow in the container..

[image]
Example of what it would look like with cards that dont fit in the container..

Comment: Are you using boostrap?

Comment: Nope, no external css libraries

Comment: But are you allowed to use any, or you simply don't want to?

Comment: I can't use any in this project

Comment: Use flexbox if you don't need support for old browsers .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yX3p9/265/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  display:table;
  background: red;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%; /* auto is default, you can have ur height here */
}

.container-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:0;
  width:90%;
  height:90%;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #eee;
  margin:10px;
}
```

[DEMO 2 with some height of the container](http://jsfiddle.net/yX3p9/266/)

Comment: I like this method for working nicely with IE compared to Flex which is annoyingly awkward, still.

Comment: Your solution centers the next rows items, instead of aligning them left - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yX3p9/267/) (resize the window), which isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: Also it doesn't break every 6 items like OP said.

Answer (score 1):

Try **Flexbox** **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/371/)**

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card{
  width:100px; 
  height:100px; 
  margin:10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="inner">
     <div class="card">1</div>
     <div class="card">2</div>
     <div class="card">3</div>
     <div class="card">4</div>
     <div class="card">1</div>
     <div class="card">2</div>
     <div class="card">3</div>
     <div class="card">4</div>
     <div class="card">3</div>
     <div class="card">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to use external libraries for your project, but there is still much to learn from them in my opinion.

Your situation is a basic example of how a grid system can be useful. In deed, this problem has been solved and equated many times before by such systems.

Normally I would suggest [Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/), but since this framework is somewhat complex, I think it would be easier to read something more lightweight, like [960 grid system](http://960.gs/). Here are two links that can give you a brief introduction into the library:

- http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/the-960-grid-system-made-easy/
- http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/using-the-960-grid-system-as-a-design-framework--webdesign-2036

Once you understand this, IMO, you have no other choice than to dive into the framework and see how it is done. It will be messy.

I also believe you will have to use JavaScript. Can you use jQuery?
Either way, when adding a new card, detect it using JavaSctipt, and then change the DOM based on that.

Hope I helped.